# How can I make a database search form with php code? What is the best way?

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, mysqli

I created many database search forms, but I'm not sure, I made theese forms and php codes well. My approach is, I concatenate the sql query from parts like below. This is just an example, I don't check if the connection was successful etc... What do you think, is there a better approach? I'd like to learn about this topic. Thanks for your answer!

class search {

```
    private $variable1 = "";
    private $variable2 = "";
    private variable3 = null;
    private $conn;
    function __construct($variable1, $variable2, $variable3) {
        $this->conn = new mysqli("servername", "username", "password", "dbname");
        $this->variable1 = $variable1;
        $this->variable2 = $variable2;
        $this->variable3 = $variable3;
    }

    public function getFromDatabase() {
        $sql_search = "SELECT * FROM tableName ";
        if ($this->variable1 != "") {
            $sql_search .= "WHERE something1 = '".$this->variable1."' ";
        }
        if ($this->variable2 != "") {
            $sql_search .= "AND something2 = '".$this->variable2."' ";
        }
        if ($this->variable3 != "") {
            $sql_search .= "AND something3 > '".$this->variable3."' ";
        }

        $result = $this->conn->query($sql_search);
        return $result;

    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->conn->close();
    }

}
```

Can I make this search code with prepared statement? I have some problems with bind_params...

Comment: If you need a code review then you should ask a question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of here.

Comment: this will lead to a sql syntax error `select * from table where x=y where z=a..`

Comment: Sorry. :D It's just a silly mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you search using `WHERE col1 = this AND col2 = that` you *narrow down* your search.  If you want a broader search you'll need `OR` in place of `AND`.

You may also want to investigate the use of `FULLTEXT` searching if you're looking for words within paragraphs.